# Filter Json response - Spring rest services

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have created rest services using Spring MVC framework & in back end am using hibernate objects to fetch the data from the DB. I am directly exposing the hibernate objects through the rest service response as it is. But now i want to filter/dont want to show, some of the fields from the domain object in the rest service response. I want to know possible & performance effective solution for this. I have tried, JsonView, JsonFilter, @JsonIngore & created a POJO which will be populated from hibernate object & then will be shown in json response. Is there any other way? and are there any drawback of using JsonFilter? BTW i have implemented all these solutions in spring rest controller class (except the @jsonIgnore, I have added this annotation in hibernate object)

Are there any drawback of using jackson objectMapper class?

thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not clear with the question. Are things not working or do you want a better way of doing ?

Comment: I am looking for better/alternate solution. When i did some research then i found that there are performance issue with JsonFilter. For some reason Jsonview is not working with Spring Hateoas. hence I am looking for any alternate solution

Comment: Try this: In your POJO (not the hibernate object) keep only those fields which you want to be part of the response and use this annotation @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) at the class level for the POJO. Doing this ignores unknown properties.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried that approach, but added the @JsonIgnoreProperties in the hibernate object. This works fine. I did that because as per my EA, we dont want to create additional  layer (pojo) to achieve the result. I believe there are only these ways to filter json reponse - JsonView, JsonFilter, @JsonIngore/@JsonIgnoreProperties & POJO. Let me know if you have any other solution :)

Comment: Nothing I know at the moment.